# Parcelable Creator Syntax

Tags: java

Can someone please elaborate on the syntax for Parcelable CREATOR here. for instance it's a static final property, but then I see a class like constructor for a Generic parameter, but no definition of class anywhere, please explain.

```
public static final Creator<Foo> CREATOR = new Creator<Foo>() {
    @Override
    public Foo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Foo(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Foo[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: This is Java code, is your question related to Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax to instantiate an instance of an anonymous class, which implements the Creator interface. [This page](https://www.baeldung.com/java-anonymous-classes) has more information on anonymous classes